# moving rows with uncheck checkbox needs to begin from a specific row

Tags: google-apps-script

I have got a script from here and now I need some adjustment.
The problem is when I have run the script all the rows above row 11 turning from dynamic into static the formulas are just gone.
I can't figure out why the script doesn't read and move below row 11.

```
function moveRows() {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Target Spreadsheet Id"); 
  var ssh=sss.getSheetByName('Source Sheet Id');
  var srg=ssh.getDataRange();
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('Target Sheet Id');  
  var oA=[];//output array for rows that meet criteria
  for(var i=svA.length-1;i>12; i--) {
    if (svA[i][21]==true) { //column 22
      oA.push(svA[i].slice()); //this copies the row array
      svA[i][21]=false; //uncheck checkbox    
    }
  }
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);//load target sheet with rows with check boxes checked       
  srg.setValues(svA);//save values in source sheet
}
```

Comment: The for loop stops before row 11 because you added the `i>12` condition. Try changing that first.

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it a lot easier to understand loops if we can increment our way through range and apparently it makes no difference to your situation so let's try it.

```
function moveRows() {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetId"); 
  var ssh=sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var srg=ssh.getRange(2,22,ssh.getLastRow()-1,1);//just column 22
  var srg1=ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow()-1,ssh.getLastColumn());//all columns for sending data to other spreadsheet.  This wont send formulas
  var svA1=srg1.getValues();
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var oA=[];//output array for rows that meet criteria
  for(var i=0;i<svA.length; i++) {
    if (svA[i][0]==true) { //column 22
      oA.push(svA1[i].slice());
      svA[i][0]=false;//uncheck checkbox    
    }
  }
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);//load target sheet with rows with check boxes checked
  srg.setValues(svA);//save values in source sheet 
}
```

So now what is the exact range that you want to loop over?  What are the rows? What are the columns? And what column has checkboxes?

And I see now that perhaps the other issue is that you have formulas that you wish to preserve so that when we reset the checkboxes we should only reset that one column.

In this version I'm only performing setValues() in the column where I have checkboxes and I still get the data to the other sheet since I'm using two arrays one that has all of the data and one that just has the checkbox column. So that should resolve your problems with formulas.